# How to load large R data.frames into Spark using SparkR's as.DataFrame()?

Tags: r, hadoop, apache-spark, sparkr

My goal is to load large R data.frame into Spark. The size of the data.frame is 5 mil. rows and 7 columns of various types. Once loaded into R, this data.frame takes up approx. 200mb of memory. However, when I try loading it into Spark using `as.DataFrame()` function, the R session gets occupied forever, it has been running for 1 hour, and I had to cancel the operation.

Here are the details:

I am creating the following dataset to using in this example:

```
n=5e6 # set sample size

d <- data.frame(
    v1=base::sample(1:9,n,replace=TRUE), 
    v2=base::sample(1000:9000,n,replace=TRUE), 
    v3=seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), by = "day")[base::sample(1:365,n,replace=TRUE)],
    v4=LETTERS[base::sample(1:length(LETTERS),n,replace=TRUE)], 
    v5=base::sample(1000:9000,n,replace=TRUE)/1000, 
    v6=seq(ISOdate(2016,1,1), ISOdate(2018,1,1), "sec")[base::sample(1:63158401,n,replace=TRUE)],
    v7=c(TRUE,FALSE)[base::sample(1:2,n,replace=TRUE)]
)
```

The above creates a sample data.frame

Size, approx 200mb:

```
paste0("size: ", round(as.numeric(object.size(d))/1000000,1)," mb")
```

Next, I create a Spark session:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME='C:\\soft\\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7',HADOOP_HOME='C:\\soft\\hadoop')
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv('SPARK_HOME'), 'R', 'lib'),.libPaths()))
Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"sparkr-shell"')

library(SparkR)
library(rJava)
sparkR.session(enableHiveSupport = FALSE,master = "local[*]", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "1g",spark.sql.warehouse.dir="C:\\soft\\hadoop\\bin"))
```

Now, I am trying to load the data.frame I created above into Spark:

```
d_sd <- as.DataFrame(d)
```

The above command takes forever to run.

Is there something wrong I am doing?
Can it be related to the class() of columns in my original R data.frame?
Should I take an alternative approach to loading large datasets from R into Spark? If yes, please feel free to suggest something.

Thank you in advance.

PS:

I am able to quickly convert and manipulate small datasets in Spark using this method.

Here is some background information on my R session and OS I am running:

R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

I am running Microsoft version of R (Revolution) under Windows 7 Professional (64 bit), 8 GB of RAM. Processor: i5-2520M @ 2.50GHz

---

**EDIT 2016-09-19:**

Thank you, Zeydy Ortiz and Mohit Bansal. Based on your answers, I have tried the following, but I am still facing the  same issue:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME='C:\\soft\\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7',HADOOP_HOME='C:\\soft\\hadoop')
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv('SPARK_HOME'), 'R', 'lib'),.libPaths()))
Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"sparkr-shell"')

library(SparkR)
library(rJava)
sparkR.session(enableHiveSupport = FALSE,master = "local[*]", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "1g",spark.sql.warehouse.dir="C:\\soft\\hadoop\\bin"))


n=5e6 # set sample size

d_sd <- createDataFrame(sqlContext,data=data.frame(
        v1=base::sample(1:9,n,replace=TRUE), 
        v2=base::sample(1000:9000,n,replace=TRUE), 
        v3=seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), by = "day")[base::sample(1:365,n,replace=TRUE)],
        v4=LETTERS[base::sample(1:length(LETTERS),n,replace=TRUE)], 
        v5=base::sample(1000:9000,n,replace=TRUE)/1000, 
        v6=seq(ISOdate(2016,1,1), ISOdate(2018,1,1), "sec")[base::sample(1:63158401,n,replace=TRUE)],
        v7=c(TRUE,FALSE)[base::sample(1:2,n,replace=TRUE)]
    ))
```

The command that converts R df to Spark df was running for several hours. Had to cancel. Please assist.

---

**EDIT 2016-12-14:**

The above was attempted using Spark 1.6.1 and R 3.2.0. I have recently tried this using Spark 2.0.2 (latest) and R 3.2.5, and I ran into the same issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with memory limitations, why do you have to create Base Dataframe first and convert that to Spark DataFrame?

You can combine both the steps into one and get results:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME='C:\\soft\\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7',HADOOP_HOME='C:\\soft\\hadoop')
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv('SPARK_HOME'), 'R', 'lib'),.libPaths()))
Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"sparkr-shell"')

library(SparkR)
library(rJava)
sparkR.session(enableHiveSupport = FALSE,master = "local[*]", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "1g",spark.sql.warehouse.dir="C:\\soft\\hadoop\\bin"))
```

Then you can load your SDF:

```
n=5e6 # set sample size

d_sd <- as.DataFrame(data.frame(
    v1=base::sample(1:9,n,replace=TRUE), 
    v2=base::sample(1000:9000,n,replace=TRUE), 
    v3=seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), by = "day")[base::sample(1:365,n,replace=TRUE)],
    v4=LETTERS[base::sample(1:length(LETTERS),n,replace=TRUE)], 
    v5=base::sample(1000:9000,n,replace=TRUE)/1000, 
    v6=seq(ISOdate(2016,1,1), ISOdate(2018,1,1), "sec")[base::sample(1:63158401,n,replace=TRUE)],
    v7=c(TRUE,FALSE)[base::sample(1:2,n,replace=TRUE)]
))
```

You can also refer to similar question: [How best to handle converting a large local data frame to a SparkR data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392327/how-best-to-handle-converting-a-large-local-data-frame-to-a-sparkr-data-frame)

Comment: Thanks, Mohit Bansal, I started a new R session, and tried your approach, it did not help. R has been running for several minutes.

Comment: @KirillSavine follow the following question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392327/how-best-to-handle-converting-a-large-local-data-frame-to-a-sparkr-data-frame

Answer (score 0):

In Spark 2.0.0, use `createDataFrame(d)`

Comment: Thank you, Zeydy Ortiz, I tried your approach. createDataFrame() function is also extremely slow using the data in my question. It has been running for some time as well. Never finished.